# How not to fill the whole body in browser?

Tags: html, css

```css
div{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}   
img{
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    padding:20px ;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MnmGmN7.jpg"  />  
</div>
```

The div will fill the whole body on my firefox.

It is not smart way ,when padding of img changed into 40px,the width of div will be changed into 160+40+40=240.

```
div{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

The desired effect is as below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on the div and it will expand to its content instead of its parent width.

*Side note, don't forget the required attribute `alt="an image description"`*

```css
div{
    display: inline-block;        /*  added  */
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
}   
img{
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    padding:20px ;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MnmGmN7.jpg" alt="image description">
</div>
```

You can do this without the div as well, unless it is needed for a specific purpose.

```css
img {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  padding:20px ;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/MnmGmN7.jpg" alt="image description">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives:

If you're okay with using [intrinsic sizing](http://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content), you can use [`fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width). However, IE/Edge does not support these values whatsoever.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MnmGmN7.jpg" />
</div>
```

As an alternative, you can always specify the size on the container and make the image a percentage of the container like so:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MnmGmN7.jpg" />
</div>
```